# Error [DF-AA-33] when downloading my Application

Tags: android, google-play

I just uploaded my App to the Google Play Store and when I try to download it I get the following error: Error retrieving information from the server [DF-AA-33]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe your app is in alpha state. I had the same problem, i realized i had to click on the invitation link on the test account before download the app, something like
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.company.app

Answer (score 2):

**These are steps:**

- Go to Settings -> Apps -> Play Store and then tap **Clear Data and Cache**
- Go to Settings -> Accounts -> Google and then **Remove Account**
- Restart your phone
- Log in with your Google Account and open Play Store.

**Done**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by

- Open Google Play Store
- Change account to the one with the proper permissions
- Install app
- Shout in victory

Comment: That solved my issue. I had multiple accounts,  and I was trying to download apk from non-permitted account.